# How to call parent class function in child class in React JS

Tags: reactjs

Following is my code snippet

**Child Class function (handleClick)**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';

export class Badge extends Component {
  handleClick() {
    alert("this and that")
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <button whenClicked={this.handleClick} className={"btn " + this.props.className} type="button">
        {this.props.title} <span className={this.props.subTitleClassName}>{this.props.subTitle}</span>
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

**Parent Class**

```
export class Dropdown extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="dropdown">
        <Badge onClicked={this.props.whenClicked} className="btn btn-default" title={this.props.title} subTitleClassName="caret" />
      </div>    
    );
  }
}
```

In above code whenever I try to call handleClick function in child class it is not working.

Comment: Event handler for click event is `onClick`. You can't name it anything you want. Also, what are you trying to do with this ? The event handler should be define in Dropdown class

Comment: You have these labeled backwards... the `Badge` is the **child** component, and the `Dropdown` is the **parent** component. So you want the `Dropdown` to handle a click on the `button` in `Badge`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got parent and child mixed up. The Dropdown component renders the Badge component, so Dropdown is the parent class.
Also the Event handler is called `onClick`.

Here's the code (in ES5):

**Dropdown**

```
var React = require('react');
var Badge = require('./Badge.react');

var Dropdown = React.createClass({

    whenClicked: function() {
        console.log('blabla');
    },

    render: function () {
        return (
            <div className="dropdown">
                <Badge whenClicked={this.whenClicked} className="btn btn-default" title={this.props.title} subTitleClassName="caret"
                subTitle="subTitle" />
            </div>  
        );
    }
});

module.exports = Dropdown;
```

**Badge**

```
var React = require('react');

var Badge = React.createClass({

    render: function () {
        return (
            <button onClick={this.props.whenClicked} className={"btn " + this.props.className} type="button">
                {this.props.title} <span className={this.props.subTitleClassName}>{this.props.subTitle}</span>
            </button> 
        );
    }
});

module.exports = Badge;
```

And in ES6:

**Badge**

```
import React from 'react';

class Badge extends React.Component {
    handleClick() {
        this.props.whenClicked();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <button onClick={this.props.whenClicked} className={"btn " + this.props.className} type="button">
                {this.props.title} <span className={this.props.subTitleClassName}>{this.props.subTitle}</span>
            </button>
        );
    }
}

module.exports = Badge;
```

**Dropdown**

```
import React from 'react';
import Badge from './Badge.react';

class Dropdown extends React.Component {
    whenClicked() {
        console.log('blabla');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="dropdown">
                <Badge whenClicked={this.whenClicked} className="btn btn-default"
                title={this.props.title} subTitleClassName="caret" subTitle="subTitle"/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

module.exports = Dropdown;
```

Comment: How to perform same thing in ES6?

Comment: es6 does automatically bind the class to non react functions so if you wanted to access `this` inside `whenClicked()` you would need to set the prop like `whenClicked={this.whenClicked.bind(this)}`

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by others, the correct name for the click event attribute is `onClick` (not `whenClick`).

**Badge (Child):**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';

export class Badge extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.props.whenClicked} className={"btn " + this.props.className} type="button">
        {this.props.title} <span className={this.props.subTitleClassName}>{this.props.subTitle}</span>
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

Which leads me to wonder: Where is your `this.props.whenClicked` defined, which you want to pass from `Dropdown` into `Badge`?

I imagine you want to define it in `Dropdown` as well and pass it in as `this.whenClicked`.

**Dropdown (Parent):**

```
export class Dropdown extends Component {
  whenClicked(event) {
      // Your event handler
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="dropdown">
        <Badge whenClicked={this.whenClicked} className="btn btn-default" title={this.props.title} subTitleClassName="caret" />
      </div>    
    );
  }
}
```

**To recap:**

1. Your `whenClicked` is defined in `Dropdown` and passed as a property into the `Dropdown` instance..
2. In badge, you define a `onClick` listener called `handleClick` which calls the `whenClicked` that you passed from Dropdown.

Comment: Actually what I am doing is this

1. Setting up my Badge as reusable component therefore I set whenClicked in it so that I call it in Dropdown with the help of props.

2. I'm able to perform same in ES5 but facing problem in ES6.

3. @weigel able to perform what I want in ES5 but I how to do in ES6.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, though I'm not entirely sure what you mean, as I don't see a huge difference between my solution and weigels solution. I have simplified it slightly in the hope that this will help to clarify. Let me know if this is (not) what you need :)

Answer (score 0):

1. The dropdown class should define the action that will be called when badge is clicked.
2. You need to pass a delegate to this function as a property to the badge. You can call the properly whatever you want.
3. In the badge class you need to change the 'whenClicked' to onClick  and pass the this.props.theNameOfTheFunction